# How to utilize MVVM in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mvvm

Someone asked me to implement MVVM in Unity and I'm sure they were not happy with my version, so I'm trying to clear things out and improve.

I know what MVC or MVVM stands for. But in Unity the "View" and "ViewModel" blur in scope. I'm not sure what does specific developers expect when they want to see a "ViewModel" in Unity.

It's more of a clear separation for MVC in Unity for me, but I have no idea what people expect when they want to see a "ViewModel".

Does it mean the Button will also have the logic script? Which sometimes seems like a horrible break of SRP when your button also initializes bullets.

**Question: How to utilize MVVM in Unity?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewModel:**

I'd expect a ViewModel to:

1. Be a component.
2. Contain properties.
3. Allow Views to be subscribed to receive updates whenever the value of a property changes.

**View:**

A View in Unity on the other hand would be a component that causes something to be drawn on the screen, or is used for receiving the user's input, such as a Button or a Renderer.

The command pattern can be used to handle button clicks in MVVM: bind a button to an ICommand or delegate type property in a ViewModel, and execute it when the button is clicked.